# What is the best way to customize a Zope object's acquisition chain?

Tags: python, zope, acquisition

Essentially, I want to check another object to see if an attribute is set there before processing the items in object.aq_chain.

I can't seem to avoid infinite recursion when overriding getattr and getattribute.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
import ExtensionClass, Acquisition

class Folder(ExtensionClass.Base): pass

class File(Acquisition.Implicit): pass

parent1 = Folder()
parent1.foo = 1
parent2 = Folder()
parent2.foo = 2

child = File()
parent1.child = child
child.otherparent = parent2

print parent1.child.foo # prints 1, but i want it to print 2
```

In case it does not go without saying, there is an API I am trying to work within.

Comment: Could you please provide concrete example. You can always use special attribute access methods, which do not trigger acquisition, but it is hard to tell anything without concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build acquisition chains, you need to use the `__of__` method of the Acquisition wrapper:

```
>>> wrapped = child.__of__(parent2)
>>> assert wrapped.aq_parent is parent2
True
```

See the [Acquisition chapter of the Zope2 documentation](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/Acquisition.html) for more information.